# Binary tree in C++ template

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, tree

I try to write a simple binary tree in C++ template. In second line of main(), I want to declare

```
Node<string,Node,int>
```

the second Node is wrong, because it's a class template, must be instantiated as

```
Node<string,Node<string,int,int>,int>
```

But as tree grows, type grows. How can I use the first declaration? Thanks!

My C++ compiler is g++ 4.8.1, support C++11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename Tl, typename Tr>
struct Node {
  // tree node
  T top;
  Tl left;
  Tr right;
  Node (const T& t=T(),const Tl& tl=Tl(),const Tr& tr=Tr()):
    top(t), left(tl), right(tr){}

};

int main() {
  Node <string,int,int> n1 (string("+"), 1, 2);
  // !!!wrong , should be Node<string,Node<string,int,int>,int>
  Node<string,Node,int> n2 (string("*"), n1, 4);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I add pointers to struct. How to make it better? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T=string, typename Tl=int, typename Tr=int>
struct Node {
  // tree node
  struct Node<T,Tl,Tr>* p_left;
  struct Node<T,Tl,Tr>* p_right;
  T top;
  Tl left;
  Tr right;
  Node (struct Node<T,Tl,Tr>* pl=nullptr, struct Node<T,Tl,Tr>* pr=nullptr,
        const T& t=T(),const Tl& tl=Tl(),const Tr& tr=Tr()):
    p_left(pl), p_right(pr), top(t), left(tl), right(tr){}
};

using tnode = struct Node<>;

int main() {
  tnode n1 (nullptr,nullptr,string("+"), 1, 2);
  tnode n2 (&n1, nullptr,string("*"), 0,0);
}
```

**UPDATE 2**, add smart pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template<typename T=string, typename Tc=int>
class Node {
public:
  Node (shared_ptr<Node> pl=nullptr, 
        shared_ptr<Node> pr=nullptr,
        const T& t=T(),
        const Tc& tl=Tc(),
        const Tc& tr=Tc()):
    p_left(pl), p_right(pr), v_top(t), v_left(tl), v_right(tr){}

  ~Node() {
    cout<<"Calling destructor"<<endl;
  }
private:
  shared_ptr<Node> p_left;
  shared_ptr<Node> p_right;
  T v_top;
  Tc v_left,v_right;
};

using tNode = Node<>;
using spNode = shared_ptr<tNode>;

spNode create_tree() {
  spNode n0 = make_shared<tNode>(nullptr,nullptr,string("*"), 7, 3);
  spNode n1 = make_shared<tNode>(nullptr,n0,string("+"), 5, 6);
  spNode n2 = make_shared<tNode>(n1, nullptr,string("+"), 3,4);
  return n2;    
}

int main() {
  spNode n2 = create_tree();
}
```

Comment: This looks way too strange. Is there something preventing you from having a `template<typename T> struct Node` and just keeping 2 pointers to `Node<T>` for the branches?

Comment: I just try to write it without pointers.

Comment: Trees work best with some kind of pointer or location.  You could use an array and the link fields would be array indices.  The main reason is that during compile time, you don't know how many nodes to use.  Thus dynamic memory is used during run-time.  Dynamic memory allocation requires pointers.

Comment: @Davy - in C# or Java, you don't need to explicitly use pointers because the members have implicit references anyway. This doesn't happen in C++. It's technically possible to have a template binary tree node defined so the parent node directly contains the child nodes without using pointers (and with different item types in different nodes, even) but it's, well, pointless. The structure of the tree as a whole would have to be fixed at compile-time, to match the big static type. You'd be better off flattening the whole tree into a single `struct` - easier to specify the type, easier to use.

Comment: Do you really need to type the type?  A function call result that you assign to `auto` might do?

Answer (score 0):

Take a `template<typename>class NodeMaker`, pass it the parent `Node` type, for the two child params.

Write `template<typename T>using Same=T;` and templatestruct fixed{templateusing type=X;}`.

Now,

```
Node<string, Same, fixed<int>::template type>
```

makes the type you want.

As a problem this type is infinite in size: you need a way for the `Node` inside `Node` to disappear.  Use `std::unique_ptr<>` to hold your left and right children?